# How to display reverse of a list using recursion?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

This code is implementation of singly linked list using c. I first element while trying to print the reverse of the list using recursive function. What is the mistake I made here? I just want to print the reverse of the list, I dont want the list to be reversed permanently, but function to reverse this permanently is also welcomed as I want to learn that too.

P.S: I should submit this code to my teacher tomorrow so please don't give corrected code in different format.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node * next;
} Node;

typedef struct list {
    Node *head;
} List;

List *emptylist() {
    List *list = malloc(sizeof(List));
    list->head = NULL;
    return list;
}

Node *createnode(int data) {
    Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

//Display reverse using recursion
void reversedis(List list) {
    if (list.head==NULL || list.head->next==NULL) return;
    else {
        list.head=list.head->next;
        reversedis(list);
        printf("%d,",list.head->data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code.

Comment: Do you really mean for your reverse display function to destroy the list?

Comment: `list.head=list.head->next;` so of course you are changing your list.

Comment: <O/T> IMO defining a `struct` with only one field is useless and bit confusing since it simply leads to one more level of indirection (if you really want to do that might as well just use a `typedef`). The exception is wrapping an array in a `struct` so you can return an array from a function if you want.

Answer (score 2):

First make sure your reversedis() does't modify the list structure

> ```
>    void reversedis(Node *node){
>        if (node==NULL) return;
>        else{
>            reversedis(node->next);
>            printf("%d,",node->data);
>        }
>    }
> ```

then in main()

> ```
>        reversedis(l->head);
> ```

Comment: He's passing his arguments by value, so he's just modifying a copy.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're changing `list.head` before you print `list.head->data`, so you lose the current element. I'm not sure why this is causing a segmentation error, though, you should just miss the first element.

Make a temporary copy of `list` and modify that.

```
void reversedis (List list) {
    if (list.head == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    List temp = list;
    temp.head = temp.next;
    reversedis(temp);
    printf("%d,", list.head->data);
}
```